# Getting the path of the current assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

How do I get the path of the current assembly? I need to get data from some paths relative to the location of hte current assembly (.dll).

I thought someone told me to use the reflection namespace but I can't find anything in there.

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use:

```
string path = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
```

Some suggestions in the comments are to pass that through `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString` *(from [vvnurmi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly#comment22517648_864497))* to ensure that any percent-encoding is handled, and to use `Path.GetFullpath` *(from [TrueWill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly#comment6266279_864497))* to ensure that the path is in standard Windows form (rather than having slashes instead of backslashes). Here's an example of what you get at each stage:

```
string s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
Console.WriteLine("CodeBase: [" + s + "]");
s = (new Uri(s)).AbsolutePath;
Console.WriteLine("AbsolutePath: [" + s + "]");
s = Uri.UnescapeDataString(s);
Console.WriteLine("Unescaped: [" + s + "]");
s = Path.GetFullPath(s);
Console.WriteLine("FullPath: [" + s + "]");
```

Output if we're running `C:\Temp\Temp App\bin\Debug\TempApp.EXE`:

```
CodeBase: [file:///C:/Temp/Temp App/bin/Debug/TempApp.EXE]
AbsolutePath: [C:/Temp/Temp%20App/bin/Debug/TempApp.EXE]
Unescaped: [C:/Temp/Temp App/bin/Debug/TempApp.EXE]
FullPath: [C:\Temp\Temp App\bin\Debug\TempApp.EXE]
```

Comment: I'd recommend calling Path.GetFullPath to turn the forward slashes into backslashes. You can get weird behavior from Assembly.LoadFile (such as the types not equating) when using forward slashes.

Comment: What is the advantage/purpose of using this instead of `.Location`? (I suspect there must be a reason, but it eludes me.)

Comment: @pst: Depending on the environment, Location can be incorrect, since shadow copying can "move" the assembly prior to execution.

Comment: @Reed: According [to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) `Location` should work in the case of shadow-copying, quote: "The location of the loaded file that contains the manifest. If the loaded file was shadow-copied, the location is that of the file after being shadow-copied.". Wouldn't that be correct behavior? Have you encountered situations where `Location` failed unexpectedly?

Comment: @Marijn That's the problem - it's the location AFTER shadow copying.  Typically, you want the location of the actual file prior to load, which the above gives you...

Comment: +1 - this is exactly what I needed for some dynamic loading of entity framework config classes. I'd give +10 if I could :)

Comment: This is very useful when running unit test, as test framework might shadow copy your assembly to a temporary folder.

Comment: When I do this I get spaces turned into '%'

Comment: Call `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString` to turn a percent-encoded file path back into a normal file path. The Uri constructor will encode e.g. spaces as "%20" which will be understood literally by .NET methods that expect conventional file paths and not URIs.

Answer (score 46):

`System.Reflection.`[`Assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx).[`GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx).[`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx)

Comment: This gives the location of mscorlib, rather than your assembly, when called from a MSTest unit test.

Answer (score 7):

Just to make it clear:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer

```
new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath;
```

EscapedCodeBase covers the scenario where your local path might have an invalid URI char in it (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056435/852208)

LocalPath includes the full path for both local paths and unc paths, where AbsolutePath trims off "\\server"