# How to get file name of .EXE

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Getting the path of the current assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly)
>   [C#: How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/c-how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Using VB 2008, how can I get the file name of a running .EXE from inside itself?

**EDIT**: This is for a console app, so `Application.ExecutablePath` will not work.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I think he's finding the path and the filename only, which is `System.IO.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few ways:

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

or

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: Ok, but Application is in System.Windows.Forms.  Is this a WinForm app?

Comment: RRUZ, I think Oplopanax has a good point about using GetEntryAssembly instead of GetExecutingAssembly.  Likewise, CodeBase is a better choice than Location, since it doesn't also include the path.

Answer (score 4):

This has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/c-how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in).

From anywhere in your code you could be in an assembly that was loaded by the originating EXE. You also may not have a reference to the Application singleton, so using the Assembly class is your best bet.

Safest way is [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx).Location gets the location on the filesystem where the Assembly is currently. If it is [shadow copied](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/07/29/4146.aspx) then this is the Shadow-copy location. If it is click-once deployed, then this is a crazy path to a file in the [sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw(VS.80).aspx) area.

The original location of the assembly will be at [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Codebase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx)

Comment: In the case of click-once deployment, will the Process method return a useful result?

Comment: I am not entirely certain, but I think the Process method will get the name of the clickonce launcher process in much the same way as for a web app it would get the IIS worker process.

Answer (score 1):

Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule

*edit*

Another way might be to use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], but I prefer using Process.

Comment: Steve  must be Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName

Comment: That's not entirely correct: you have a choice between getting the FileName or the ModuleName.

Comment: ModuleName Gets the main module for the associated process. not the filename.

Comment: Depending on what you need, that may be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should find it in the property: [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx)