# How can I make an application run with one specific name?

Tags: vb.net

I want my application to run by a certain name, example:"Coisinho.exe" and if they change it to any other name, it would be a "violation of the software" because it is supposed to be named that way so that the other components work properly. Basically if they the change application name I want it to shutdown right after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file name of .EXE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460684/how-to-get-file-name-of-exe)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Paulo is asking a different question to that question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName <> "Coisinho.exe" Then
    Application.Exit()  /// in a console-app: Environment.Exit(1)
    Return
End If
```