# How to get the path of the dll within the function inside the dll in C#?

Tags: c#

Let me ask how to get the file path of the dll within a function inside the dll  in C# 4.0?
Please let me know how only using C# ,but not using win API directly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See previous question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string currentAssemblyDirectoryName = 
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

> Beware that Assembly.Location property returns the location of the
>   assembly file after it is shadow-copied. In addition , if it is
>   dynamically loaded using Load method, it returns empty string .
>
> If you are interested in retrieving
>   the location of the assembly before it is shadow-copied or loaded, 
>   use Assembly.CodeBase property instead. Please note that, it is the
>   location specified originally while stating the AssemblyName.

Reference [here](http://adilakhter.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/get-current-executing-assemblys-directory/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Although if you are inside an ASP.NET application, due to shadow copying, this is probably not the location that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.GetType().Assembly.Location;
```