# Assembly.Location doesn't returns dll location

Tags: .net

I'm looking for a way to return my assembly location at runtime, I can't use Assembly.Location because it returns the shadow-copied assembly's path when running under NUnit.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/864497/1373170

Comment: So `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` doesn't provide the right path?

Answer (score 3):

Use CodeBase property instead, it return the original dll location rather than the shadow copied dll location.

For example:

```
Assembly assembly = GetType().Assembly;    
Uri codeBaseUri = new Uri(assembly.CodeBase);
string path = codeBaseUri.LocalPath;
```