# Build output file path in windows service application

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service that reads a file upon creation.

I added the file to my project, set it's **Buid Action** to *Content* and **Copy to Output Directory** to *Copy always*, and used the following to get the file path:

```
private const string MEDIA_PLAYER_FILENAME = "mediaPlayers.xml";
var mediaPlayerFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, MEDIA_PLAYER_FILENAME);
```

This works well when I self-host it In a Console app, but when it is being hosted in Windows Service, it fails because it tries to read it from **C:\Windows\system32\mediaPlayers.xml**

I guess `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is not the one I should use. What should it be? or is there another approch to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the path of the executing assembly. The CurrentDirectory is not the same thing.

See this post for getting that information:

[Getting the path of the current assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864484/getting-the-path-of-the-current-assembly)

Re-post:

```
(new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
```

Or

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```